# A custom function for joining cells and an optional value from an adjacent cell in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Item     |   Count   |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Milk     |     1     |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Cereal   |     3     |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Bread     |     2      |
```

When I use the JOIN function, I would get something like `Milk, Cereal, Bread`. What I want to do is add the value from the count column, but only if the value is greater than 1. So a custom function would print something like `Milk, Cereal x3, Bread x2`  How could I achieve this in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(B2:B*1>1, A2:A&" x"&B2:B, A2:A)))
```

[image: 0]